# How to check the country origin of a url

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of url's and want to find out their country of origin via python 3. And was wondering if anyone could help.

For example: `quikr.com` or `kooora.com`

Thanks

Comment: Have you already tried something like [https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy)?

Comment: @AlexVorndran thank you. I didn't find it before but will give it a try.

Comment: Here is a newer version [geograpy3](https://pypi.org/project/geograpy3/)

Comment: @AlexVorndran, geograpy it is not working as hoped. The following code returns an empty list and was hoping to see `USA` or so.
```from geograpy import extraction
e = extraction.Extractor(url='http://www.nike.com/')
e.find_entities()
print(e.places)
```

Comment: https://geoip2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[geoip2](https://geoip2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

either via a database, you need to download (which I did) or create an account.

Thanks @AlexVorndran for the initial help.

Code example:

```
import geoip2.database
import socket

ip = socket.gethostbyname('nike.com')
reader = geoip2.database.Reader('GeoLite2-Country_20190305/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')
response = reader.country(ip)
response.country.iso_code # Results in 'US'
```